# Relation between $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{2}$ Norms of a Lebesgue function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Can $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ norm of a function $f(t)$ be related with its $\mathcal{L}_{2}$ norm as $||f||_{1} \leq ||f||_{\infty} ||f||_{2}$ or something like this?

Comment: If the domain has finite measure, then you can apply Holder's to get $\|f\|_1\le C\|f\|_2$, where $C$ depends on the measure of the domain.

Comment: Thank you.. Does C depends on the time T i.e., limit of the integration?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That one also looks like it fails homogeneity wrt $f$...

Comment: You didn't mention any $T$ in the statement of the question. Please edit the question to state it precisely.

Comment: The correct interpolation inequality is this one: $\|f\|_2\le\|f\|_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}\|f\|_\infty^\frac{1}{2}$ (thanks to @HomegrownTomato for spotting the missing exponent in my previous comment)